# Add optional @ or not?

Tags: blazor

Both versions work but which is the right choice? This?

```
<button type="button @onclick="NavigateToHome">
```

Or this (note the extra @)?

```
<button type="button @onclick="@NavigateToHome">
```

Comment: Recommended? Whose recommendation are you asking for? If you're asking for the official recommendation, I would instead rephrase your question to ask what is right. If you're asking for people's recommendations, your question will most likely be closed as being primarily based on opinions. Or, I would ask what the difference is, and then you make up your own recommendation based on that.

Comment: You're right. I updated it, hopefully it's more clear now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the early stages of development of the Blazor framework, we had to prepend the `@` sign to the name of the method to tell the compiler that the value of a given attribute, such as onclick is C# executable code.

It looked like this: onclick="@NavigateToHome"

Later on, compiler directive were introduced, as for instance the `@onclick` compiler directive.

As a result, this constraint had been removed, and you can use the name of the method only  like this: `NavigateToHome`:

```
@onclick="NavigateToHome"
```

No need to tell the compiler that `NavigateToHome` is a C# method that should be called when an element is clicked.

The introduction of the compiler directives also made a distinction between `@onclick` and `onclick`. The following code sample demonstrate this idea:

```
<button type="button" onclick="alert("Alert...");">Click me now</button>
```

If you click on the button now, the alert window will be displayed. In other words, JavaScript is executed.

As far as I can recall, it was Daniel Roth who said in one of the previews for Blazor, that they are not going to enforce the removal of the `@` sign. In other words, it was made backward compatible. So you can use both constructs. Out of habit I always use the `@` sign. There was a time I tried to teach myself to not use it, but it was too late. As you are a new Blazor learner's it would be a good idea if you don't use the `@` sign from the start.

Note, however, that the `@` sign must be used with lambda expression, as for instance: `@onclick="@( (args) => NavigateToHome(args))"`

It's important to remember that `@onclick` is a compiler directive instructing the compiler to create the pipeline for calling the `NavigateToHome' method.

But if you use a `value` attribute, as for instance:

```
<input type="text' value="@<property-name>"
```

the property name must always be preceded with the `@` sign, which instruct the compiler to create the pipeline to call the method (executable C# code). Failing to do so, will result in the value attribute being set to the string value of the property identifier.

Comment: I'm going from Angular --> Blazor, so yes I'm relatively new and I got confused by people sometimes using @ and sometimes not. This detailed answer is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you.

Comment: Funny, I did the same, but it was over two years ago, and I've never regretted it.